# Modificar estructura de datos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, matriz

Tengo una estructura que me llega de la siguiente forma:

```
[
  0: { 
       id: "PJH",
       nombre: "Test",
       apellido: "Test",
       materias: [
                   0: { materia: "test", carrera: "test"}
                 ]
     }

 1: {
      id: "KSJ",
      nombre: "Test 2",
      apellido: "Test 2",
      materias: [
                 0: { materia: "test 2", carrera: "test 2" }
                 1: { materia: "test 2.1", carrera: "test 2.1" }
               ]
   }
]
```

¿Hay alguna forma de convertirlo en esta otra?

```
[
  0: { 
       id: "PJH",
       nombre: "Test",
       apellido: "Test",
       materia: "test",
       carrera: "test" 
     }

 1: {
      id: "KSJ",
      nombre: "Test 2",
      apellido: "Test 2",
      materia: "test 2",
      carrera: "test 2"
      materia_2: "test 2.1"
      carrera_2: "test 2.1"
   }
]
```

Es para implementar una función que genera un archivo CSV, a la cual le tengo que pasar una matriz de objetos.

Si le paso los datos como vienen solo puedo leer los datos de `id`, `nombre` y `apellido` y la matriz de materias llega como `[OBJECT, OBJECT]`.

Comment: Poder, se puede, ¿pero no sería mejor corregir el código que lee esos campos en vez de complicar el nombre de las propiedades? Acceder a varios elementos de una matriz es más sencillo que buscar propiedades que tienen un nombre base y, posiblemente, un sufijo con `_2`, `_3`, etc.

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario, no entiendo a que te refieres con "el código que lee esos campos", el nombre de las propiedades no importa en realidad, lo que importa es sacar los elementos del array que esta dentro de cada objeto y agregarlos como propiedades del objeto como muestro en el ejemplo.

Comment: Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué necesitas convertir el origen al destino? ¿Es porque hay otra función o aplicación que debe acceder a esa información y no le gusta encontrar en ella una matriz en vez de una cadena de caracteres? En ese caso, es mejor revisar el correcto funcionamiento de dicha función que aplicar malas prácticas de nomenclatura de propiedades a un objeto que estaba bien estructurado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías plantearte mejorar la función que usas para convertir los datos de entrada a CSV para que acepte los datos tal y como vienen de origen.

Aunque deberías evitar reestructurar los datos de entrada, aquí te dejo cómo podrías hacerlo:

```js
let datos = [
  { 
    id: "PJH",
    nombre: "Test",
    apellido: "Test",
    materias: [
      { materia: "test", carrera: "test"},
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "KSJ",
    nombre: "Test 2",
    apellido: "Test 2",
    materias: [
      { materia: "test 2", carrera: "test 2" },
      { materia: "test 2.1", carrera: "test 2.1" },
    ],
  },
];

/* Reajustamos el contenido */
datos.forEach((dato, indice) => {
  for (const propiedad in dato) {
    /* Si no es una cadena, genero las propiedades extra */
    //if (typeof(dato[propiedad]) != "string") {
    if (Array.isArray(dato[propiedad]) === true) {
      /* Analizamos cada elemento */
      dato[propiedad].forEach((subdato, subindice) => {
        /* Convertimos cada propiedad */
        for (const subpropiedad in subdato) {
          /* Si es el índice 0 no agregamos sufijo */
          const nueva = subpropiedad + (subindice ? ("_" + (subindice + 1)) : "");
          dato[nueva] = subdato[subpropiedad];
        }
      });
      /* Borramos el elemento anterior */
      delete dato[propiedad];
    }
  }
});

/* Mostramos los datos tras tratarlos */
console.log(datos);
```

Comment: Agradezco tu aporte Oscar esto soluciona mi problema, lo que convierte los datos a CSV es una librería, voy a investigar de como hacer la funcionalidad yo mismo para aprender un poco mas. Gracias y saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál usas? Probablemente tenga alguna función o retrollamada para procesar los datos de cada fila.

Comment: Estoy usando react-csv, aca te comparto el link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

Comment: Parece que no está preparado para hacer procesamiento personalizado. Te proporciona una implementación para diferentes tipos de procesamiento: matrices multidimensionales, matrices de objetos y cadenas que contengan datos CSV. No soporta expandir su funcionalidad más allá de la que tiene programada.

Answer (score 0):

Si que puedes hacerlo. Por ejemplo
Si origen es elobjeto de partida

```
    for(j=0; j < origen.length; j++){
        destino[j]={}
        destino[j].id = origen[j].id;
        destino[j].nombre= origen[j].nombre;
        destino[j].apellido= origen[j].apellido;
        for(i=0; i < origen[j].materias.length; i++){
            destino[j]['materia_'+i] = origen[j].materias[i].materia;
            destino[j]['carrera_'+i] = origen[j].materias[i].carrera;
        }
    }
```

Si no quieres poner el _0 le colocas un if para que si i=0 no lo añada a tu gusto.
Esto es lo más simple, también podrís recorrer las keys del objeto origen y en caso de que sean tipo array entrar en el bucle de i. Y las keys del destino además serían leídas del origen. Pero como tienes una estructura fija y asís es más evidente, pues te dejo esta solución.
**EDITO**
Me he picado un poco con esto de recorrer objetos, esta modificación lo automatiza aún más:

```
   destino=[] 
   for(j=0; j < origen.length; j++){
        destino[j]={}
        for(key in origen[j]){
            if (Array.isArray(origen[j][key])){
                for(i=0; i < origen[j][key].length; i++){
                    for(kmat in origen[j][key][i]){ 
                            sub = i==0?'':"_"+(i+1);   
                            destino[j][kmat+sub] = origen[j][key][i][kmat];
                        }
                    }
                }
            else{
                destino[j][key] = origen[j][key]
                }
            }
        }
```

Como ves ahora las claves del objeto destino las lee del origen y si encuentra un array lo recorre así como sus elementos (que son objetos).
Además los nombres de materia y carrera llevan el sufijo como pones en la pregunta materia, materia_2
Una solución simple con poco código, y creo que fácil de seguir y entender.
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Me alegra ver que has usado la misma técnica que yo para detectar que un elemento es una matriz y no tener que escribir las propiedades a mano y también la manera de nombrar el nuevo índice. Como mejora, te aconsejo que procures definir mejor las variables, marcándolas como `const` cuando éstas no deberían ser modificadas, `let` cuando sean de ámbito de bloque (un bucle, por ejemplo), etc, ya que en caso contrario estás envenenando el ámbito global de variables con variables que dejaste de usar (como `sub`, `j`, `i`, etc).

Comment: Para eso está el método, el resto es iterar objetos, como tiene propiedades iterables pues la solución es muy evidente.  El recorrido del array a base de for es muy simple e intuitiva.    
Cierto no he cuidado ámbitos y declaraciones, me castigo duramente :)